# How to disable chrome redirecting http to http requests

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, http, https, redirection

So I've got a vm running and I've updated /etc/hosts on the host machine using `dev` to point the the VM IP. When using chrome however e.g `dev:5000/some/path` it redirects me to `http://dev:5000/some/path`

I've already attempted the suggestions in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https, but that doesn't work for me. Any idea how to disable https redirection?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so found a workaround. Updated my /etc/hosts from `dev` to `dev.local`